# Store JSONObject inside RealmObject

Tags: realm

I am writing a delayed network task queue  in which we start making network request from realm db as soon as internet is connected.
So when ever a network task is created it will be pushed in realm db queue.The NetworkTask should have the JSONObject parameters which has be sent with Network Post Request.

But JSONObject is not supported in realm currently.

If there is some way to achieve this.Could someone share his/her knowledge.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but inserting JSON objects through Realm is supported by the `Realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson()` methods.

If you want to store a JSON object in Realm, the easiest would be to do so as a String and do the conversion in the getters and setters:

```
public class Foo extends RealmObject {

  private String json;

  public void setJson(JSONObject jsonObj) {
    json = jsonObj.toString();
  }

  public JSONObject getJson() {
     return new JSONObject(json);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian for the quick reply. Since it might be an expensive operation so i wanted to avoid that. But to use realm i think we have to go with this approach only.

Comment: I noticed `JSObject.toString()` converts floats to `int`